# Multiple dropdown toggles

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I have the following script which is partially working.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navigation3">
    click me
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="items">icon Default 3</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.navigation3').click(function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(".dropdown").toggle();
});​
```

The `.active` part works were the clicked `.navigtion3`s become red, if I click all three, all three go red.

The bit which is not working is the `.dropdown`.  It should be dropping directly under the `.navigtion3` divs.  Plus at the moment, it is only displaying 1 `.dropdown` at a time, it should display all if all the `.navigation3`s are `.active`.

Also, based on user selection, I will not know how many `.navigation3`s and `.dropdown`s will be displayed on the users screen.

I can't seem to get this to work and would appreciate some jQuery expert help.

**jsFiddle:**

This is what I currently have:
http://jsfiddle.net/MTESY/12/

Comment: Position: absolute puts the div 40px from the top of the page, not from the dropdown, you need to use relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this http://jsfiddle.net/chrismoutray/MTESY/16/

```
$('.navigation3').click(function(event) {
    var $nav3 = $(this),
        $dd = $nav3.next('.dropdown');

    $nav3.toggleClass('active');

    var offset = 30,
        offsettop = $nav3.offset().top + $nav3.height() + offset,
        offsetleft = $nav3.offset().left;

    $dd.css({
        top: offsettop,
        left: offsetleft
    });

    $nav3.hasClass('active') ? $dd.show() : $dd.hide();
});
```

The 2 bits to focus on here are; find the correct *dropdown* element

```
$nav3.next('.dropdown');
```

And make sure to place the element correctly

```
$dd.css({
    top: offsettop,
    left: offsetleft
});
```

Its not perfect but it will get you started

Comment: That is fairly close, thanks.  I will start with this and get back asap.

Answer (score 0):

you can attach your division based on your current cursor position

```
   $('.navigation3').click(function(event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(".dropdown").css('left',event.pageX-10);   
        $(".dropdown").css('top',event.pageY+10);  
        $(".dropdown").toggle();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MTESY/14/

Comment: Clearly better than my version, but it is possible to 1. align the top-right corner of the `.dropdown` with the bottom-right corner of the clicked on `.navigation3`? 2. Stop an active `.dropdown` from disappearing if a different `.navigation3` is clicked?

Comment: @oshirowanen:follow Chris solution,as it is clearly a better one than mine.Mine will make the dropdown div appear relative to the cursor current position which is not good compare to offset position that Chris has used.

Answer (score 0):

There is error in the script :

```
$('.navigation3').click(function(event) {
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
   $(".dropdown").toggle(); // means toggle all the "dropdown". So if one is visible it will go invisible and vice-versa
});​
```

Check : http://jsfiddle.net/Agh3Z/ 
Please note that all the "dropdown" divs are getting displayed at same position. So you display them all by changing their positions.

Comment: How do I correct this, do I need to use some form of find/closest `.dropdown`?

Comment: I have posted a solution for fixing the issue on jsfiddle. Here the class names may seem impertinent. You can use some counter to track the number of "dropdown" or you can find the relevant "dropdown" by using something like : $(".dropdown")[NUMBER]  where number could be serial number of $(".navigation3") being clicked.